# Is there any way to obtain contact list of specific path in a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Here we have a case which needs to export contacts who passed a specific path in journey to 3rd party system. Is there any way to catch those contacts and add them to specified data extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run a large number of journeys that have a similar requirement. Our solution was to create a Journey_Flags DE and update this within each Journey via an 'Update Contact' step with relevant campaign codes, entry/exit datetimes, path flags, etc.

This way we can keep a rich record of customers' journey progressions in one DE, makes that data easily available for other journeys/filters/etc to reference, gives us plenty of flexibility to expand and adjust, and makes it simple to export for reporting and other tasks.

Comment: Hi Rainer, it seems to be a good idea, there's more information long for your elaboration. 1) Since 'Update Contact' activity uses Contact Key to map and update DE attribute value, it means I can have only one record for each contact, how can I record contact journey history in multiple journeys in one single DE? 2) Does that mean I have to use different DE for each Journey? Many thanks!

Comment: Our solution was to expand horizontally, in that we created a number of standard columns that we add to the table for each new journey we add. This way there's one master record of all the customers' journey activity, making it easy to integrate into the data model, simple to reference in filters, easy to export, and so on. This doesn't work as well if you have journeys that allow for an anytime re-entry, but this can be worked around. If you prefer to keep use a transactional model, that's possible with a some basic SQL + 2 DE's to store current activity and a historical record.

Comment: Got it. Just curious how many fields have you created in this DE so far?  :)

Comment: We have 107 fields so far, covering 21 unique journeys.